# jMock Expectations Not Specified

Tags: java, mocking, jmock

I'm new to jMock, so I'm trying it out on a simple example. I can't figure out why it's not working, though. Here's the class that I'm testing:

```
package com.application;

import com.domain.Coordinate;
import com.domain.Playable;

public class ChessFacade {

    private final Playable board;

    public ChessFacade(Playable aBoard) {
        board = aBoard;
    }

    public void showPotentialMoves(Coordinate aCoordinate) {
        board.getTileOccupancy(aCoordinate);
    }

}
```

And here's my Mock Object test:

```
package unit.application;

import application.ChessFacade;
import com.domain.Coordinate;
import com.domain.Playable;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.jmock.integration.junit4.JMock;
import org.jmock.integration.junit4.JUnit4Mockery;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class ChessFacadeTest extends TestCase {

    public void testFacadeGetsPotentialMovesFromBoard() {
        Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();
        final Playable mockBoard = context.mock(Playable.class);
        ChessFacade facade = new ChessFacade(mockBoard);

        final Coordinate locationToShow = new Coordinate(0, 0);
        facade.showPotentialMoves(locationToShow);

        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            oneOf(mockBoard).getTileOccupancy(locationToShow);
        }});

        context.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Testcase: testFacadeGetsPotentialMovesFromBoard(unit.application.ChessFacadeTest):        Caused an ERROR
unexpected invocation: playable.getTileOccupancy(<Coordinate{row=0column=0}>)
no expectations specified: did you...
 - forget to start an expectation with a cardinality clause?
 - call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?
what happened before this: nothing!
java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected invocation: playable.getTileOccupancy(<Coordinate{row=0column=0}>)
no expectations specified: did you...
 - forget to start an expectation with a cardinality clause?
 - call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?
what happened before this: nothing!
        at org.jmock.internal.InvocationDispatcher.dispatch(InvocationDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jmock.internal.InvocationDispatcher.dispatch(InvocationDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jmock.Mockery.dispatch(Mockery.java:218)
        at org.jmock.Mockery.access$000(Mockery.java:43)
        at org.jmock.Mockery$MockObject.invoke(Mockery.java:258)
        at org.jmock.internal.InvocationDiverter.invoke(InvocationDiverter.java:27)
        at org.jmock.internal.FakeObjectMethods.invoke(FakeObjectMethods.java:38)
        at org.jmock.lib.JavaReflectionImposteriser$1.invoke(JavaReflectionImposteriser.java:33)
        at $Proxy0.getTileOccupancy(Unknown Source)
        at application.ChessFacade.showPotentialMoves(ChessFacade.java:15)
        at unit.application.ChessFacadeTest.testFacadeGetsPotentialMovesFromBoard(ChessFacadeTest.java:22)
```

Comment: You might have to define your expectations before you call the facade method instead of after.

Comment: @rsp - make that an answer, because it is the answer.  You do have to set expectations before the call.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Make that an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have to define your expectations before you call the facade method instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you appear to be mixing JUnit 3 and 4. I suggest you just go with one. The @RunWith(JMock.class) is for 4, otherwise you need to the TestCase class that comes with JMock's JUnit 3 integration.

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving around code for (a) creating mocks and (b) setting expectations on mocks as called out in above answers as well as [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15536739/3679900) without luck.

Eventually I moved from `org.jmock.Mockery` to just plain old `org.mockito.Mockito.mock` and that worked.