# jMock "unexpected invocation" for a method that I have a oneOf(instance).method() expected

Tags: java, jmock

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

This is the method I'm testing:

```
public List<Mo> filterDuplicatesByName(List<Mo> dbMos) {
    List<String> names = Lists.newArrayList();
    for(Mo mo : dbMos) {
        try {
            String name = mo.getName();
            if(names.contains(name)) {
                dbMos.remove(mo);
            } else {
                names.add(name);
            }
        } catch (DataLayerException ex) {
            dbMos.remove(mo);
        }
    }
    return dbMos;
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
package com.rondavu.wt.service.recommendations;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.rondavu.data.api.Mo;
import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.jmock.lib.legacy.ClassImposteriser;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class RecommendationsUtilsTest  {

    Mockery context = new Mockery();

    RecommendationsUtils recommendationsUtils = new RecommendationsUtils();

    final Mo mo = context.mock(Mo.class);

    @Test
    public void testFilterDuplicatesByName_oneMo() throws DataLayerException {
        List<Mo> input = Lists.newArrayList(mo);
        List<Mo> expected = Lists.newArrayList(mo);

        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            oneOf (mo).getName(); will(returnValue("Mo 1"));
        }});

        List<Mo> actual = recommendationsUtils.filterDuplicatesByName(input);

        context.assertIsSatisfied();

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get this output:

```
unexpected invocation: mo.getName()
no expectations specified: did you...
 - forget to start an expectation with a cardinality clause?
 - call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?
what happened before this: nothing!
    [stack trace]
```

I'm pretty new to jMock, and Java is not my strongest language in general but I thought that my `oneOf (mo).getName()` would make it expect that invocation. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's not clear why at this point, it seems like Mockery is checking a different instance of mo compared to the one you're defining the expectations to. Try inserting `context.mock(Mo.class)` in the same local scope as the test case (or in an @Before method) and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I moved the `final Mo mo = context.mock(Mo.class);` from the class definition to the beginning of the `testFilterDuplicatesByName_oneMo()` method and it started working!

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. I'd make very sure you understand exactly what the difference is. 
While you're at it, I'd suggest using the allowing() clause because you're just querying a value--or even just a real object if that's possible.
Also, you should look at the JUnit4RuleMockery rather than explicitly checking the context.

Comment: This answered helped me despite my solution being different.  Thanks for the hints on the different instance!